# Bootstrap 5: Change height/use padding for option element

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I wish to change the height or increase padding-top + padding-bottom of the **option** element in a normal select box when using Bootstrap 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/

How is this possible? Example code:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option> <!-- class="h-25 pt-3 pb-3" does not work -->
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Custom  menus need only a custom class, .form-select to
> trigger the custom styles. Custom styles are limited to the ’s
> initial appearance and cannot modify the s due to browser
> limitations.

quote from [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/#default)

It is basically not possible [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css). You can use plugins in your code or use [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) instead of `select`.

Comment: this seems to be the case, indeed. i will use dropdown as suggested. thx